# How to add a static User field to django query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to perform some special serialization / deserialization with DRF, but one of the required parameters for those is the user that generated the query.

AFAIK a `serializers.Field` instance does not have access to `ViewSet` and thus no access to `ViewSet.request.user`.

So I thought I'd just add the user as a static field into the queryset so that each record would have access to it.

```
qry = qry.annotate(user=Value(user, models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)))
```

However, this gives me

```
ValueError: Related model 'auth.User' cannot be resolved
```

I also tried

```
q.annotate(user=Value(user, models.ForeignKey(user.__class__)))
```

but that also excepts.

Exactly what do I have to include so that this will resolve as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`CurrentUserDefault`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

> A default class that can be used to represent the current user. In order to use this, the `'request'` must have been provided as part of the context dictionary when instantiating the `serializer`.
>
> ```
> owner = serializers.HiddenField(
>     default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
> )
> ```

To use this, you need to [pass the request in the context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) as following:

```
serializer = AccountSerializer(account, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: Actually, this works out of the box for me. `self.context['request'].user` in `Field.to_representation`